# Bland's Ratio Details

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

[Bland's Finite Pivoting Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland's_rule) is often used as the standard pivoting rule in simplical optimization for linear programs. However, some literature conflicts - for maximization, some state that *only the denominator* (the coefficient in the tableau) need be positive, while [others](https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/30210/30210_F07/presentations/simplex_full.pdf) (see step 9) suggest that *only the ratio* need be positive. The competing possabilities:

$\forall const, coeff : \mathbb{Q} | coeff > 0. \frac{const}{coeff}$

vs.

$\forall const, coeff : \mathbb{Q} | \frac{const}{coeff} > 0. \frac{const} {coeff}$

I could see how the denominator's restriction could be more logical; as it avoids division by zero. However, I still can't rule out the other case, due to the number of books and tutorials I've seen that abuse this edge case.

---

## Edit:

I am actually entirely incorrect about this - this ratio is canonical for **all** simplex methods, and Bland's rule is merely oriented on the assumption of indicies identifying the row and columns of coefficients in the tableau.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an authoritative source that explicitly show's that the *second* option is the correct one - Linear Programming and Extensions, by Dantzig (the original pioneer of simplex method):

$\forall const, coeff : \mathbb{Q} | coeff > 0, const \ge 0. \frac{const}{coeff}$

---

## Edit:

Again as stated in the question - this rule is for **all** simplex methods - this measure captures the *amount* of allowable growth until breaking the positivity restriction on the entry variable you pivot over - such that this is the distance *increased* in the matroid.